# JavaScript doesn't run in any browser & is enabled - Have replaced document.write for alert and still wouldn't work

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, alert, document.write

I'm trying this seemingly simple snippet where the only var 'numero' must return a random number as if it were a dice so the range must go from 1 to 6 and it works BUT it only runs when I insert the whole JavaScript code inside the HTML like a `script` like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript Dice</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var numero = Math.random();
    numero = numero * 6;
    numero++;
    numero = Math.floor(numero);
    document.write("Random dice number is: " + numero + "<br><br>")
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>This is the main</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Although, I get a lot that I must not use `document.write();`since it's a bad practice (It makes it run slowly or something? I'm still reading my way up to it) and I've tried applying the solutions I've seen in other questions but they're so specific I felt I would've messed up because were hard to implement with such specific elements. So, please, what could I use instead of `document.write`in this case?

MY BIG QUESTION IS why the code below DOESN'T work?

- My first attempt was to link a JavaScript file from HTML as in:

```js
// The Math Object
var numero = Math.random();
numero = numero * 6;
numero = Math.floor(numero);
numero++;
document.write("Random number: " + numero + "<br><br>");
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript dice</title>
  <script src="MathObject.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>This is the main </p>
</body>

</html>
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK IN ANY BROWSER - I've checked if JavaScript is enabled, I've restarted settings, I've tried Chrome, Edge, Internet Explorer, it only works in the Split/Live view of the code inside DreamWeaver CC 2017 itself which is of no use but I know the code works
Which just returns:This is the main.

I even replaced the `document.write`with an alert message just to test it more and it DIDN'T work either unless I run it inside of DreamWeaver or the code editor in here.

```js
// The Math Object
var numero = Math.random();
numero = numero * 6;
numero = Math.floor(numero);
numero++;
alert("Random number: " + numero);
```

I went crazy trying to seek a solution but decided to implement all JavaScript in HTML. There must be a solution for this or a more appropriate way since I need this to be printed on the document.

TO CLARIFY:
- JavaScript only works when it's completely inside the HTML like a script
- I don't want to print many numbers or a loop. Just one.
- How can I print something from JavaScript on the document without having to write everything on the HTML
Any help with all this, please? Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Open up the developer tools in your browser. I am guessing you have a 404, file not found. Is the .js file in the same folder as the html file?

Comment: `document.write()` writes over your entire document.

Comment: @PHPglue not really true.... why would the alert fail and why would the original script work?

Comment: Are you trying code at `file:` protocol?

Comment: The file is perfectly and safely linked using the tools from DreamWeaver itself. I've worked with files not in the same folder more than enough times. I could positively say it's safe.

Comment: the code you are showing here works perfectly fine in plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/JLZTNxL2UuBBbVnP0XXf?p=preview.  It *seems like* @ObsidianAge is correct with their answer, that if it's not working on your system, it's likely a path problem.  It's still a *terrible idea* to use `document.write()`, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: Is there any error getting logged in browser console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an issue regarding **file reference**. If you check your **[F12 Developer Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx)**, it's probably telling you that it can't find the file `MathObject.js`.

On your line `<script src="MathObject.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">`, you are stating that `MathObject.js` is **in the same folder** as the page you are including it on.

You may simply have forgotten to include it in the project, but it's more likely that you referenced it incorrectly. Depending on where your `MathObject.js` file actually resides, you probably need to change this reference.

- You can use the **relative link** `../MathObject.js` to navigate up one folder.
- You can use the **root-relative link** `/MathObject.js` to always reference the root.
- You can use the **absolute link** `https://example.com/MathObject.js` to load a hosted version.

For further reading on relative and absolute URLs, I recommend checking out this **[Coffee Cup article](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, this is all quite useful but I'm afraid the file is perfectly linked as I always verify it to be. I don't even write the links myself even if I could. I link it using the tools from DreamWeaver itself. And it displays it when editing the code.

Comment: Hmm, I'm almost sure that's the cause -- it wouldn't hurt to confirm it at least. What does your folder structure look like? Where is your main HTML file, and where is `MathObject.js`? Also, are you making use of `partials` / `includes` at all? Because that would break the structure. Like, with PHP, including a file `/subfolder/two.php` on `/one.php` with the JS in `/subfolder/` would have the JavaScript work for `two.php` but **not** `one.php`.

Comment: YES, I had to reestructure everything since the root site had been set on a different disk and all so that took me a while. It's weird how files don't work when they are outside their root files... Well, not always. This is the first case of that kind that I've come across. All my other linked files in HTML have worked despite being outside the root site folder. That's why I firmly believed it wouldn't have affected it but this is how these things go sometimes. Thank you, it was a little bothersome to reestructure but very much so necessary! WORKED & SOLVED

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully, you can learn something from this:

```js
//<![CDATA[
// external.js
var pre = onload, doc, bod, C, E, rollEm; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre(); // change var pre if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
C = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var out = E('out'), dice = E('dice'), dv;
function rollEm(dice, sides, outputRowElement){
  outputRowElement.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i=0,td,l=dice; i<l; i++){
    td = C('td'); td.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*sides)+1;
    outputRowElement.appendChild(td);
  }
}
E('roll').onclick = function(){
  dv = dice.value;
  if(!dv.match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
    dv = dice.value = 1;
  }
  rollEm(dv, 6, out);
}
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:940px; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
label{
  margin-right:4px;
}
#dice{
  width:40px;
}
td{
  padding:5px; border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Lame Dice</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='main'>
      <label for='dice'>Dice</label><input id='dice' name='dice' type='text' value='1' /><input id='roll' name='roll' type='button' value='Roll &apos;em' />
      <table><tbody><tr id='out'></tr></tbody></table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll have to chalk the downvote up to jealousy. Must be a, I have to have more points than you so I'm going downvote you to stay on top, kind of thing, because, as you can see, there's a bunch of useful techniques in my code.